# How do I change image url interchangeably on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create something like **read more** with arrow up and arrow down. However, in this case, I am not changing the text but the arrow up and arrow down interchangeably. 
If I click on the **Profile** the `Arrow Down` should change to `Arrow Up` (without the text changing).

```
$('.accordion-tab').click(function(){
           if($(this).css("background-image") === "url(https://myprofile.com/wp-content/uploads/Nav-Arrow-Down.png)"){
               $(this).css("background-image", "url(https://myprofile.com//wp-content/uploads/Nav-Arrow-Up.png)");
           }else{
               $(this).css("background-image", "url(https://myprofile.com//wp-content/uploads/Nav-Arrow-Down.png)");
           }
```

From the code, I was trying to check the background-image upon the currently assigned URL to determine which one to change it to.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `background-image` property set inline on the element in the style attribute?

Comment: Yes it is set inline

Comment: `console.log($(this).css("background-image"))` to see what values are being returned to see what's up with your if statement

Comment: Yes, when I did it displays url( https://myprofile.com/wp-content/uploads/Nav-Arrow-Down.png)

Comment: So "url(myprofile.com/wp-...." doesn't match your if conditional, yeah?

Comment: I included it now and still not displaying

Comment: I did edit it now still not working

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to keep using the console log method to look at what the value is being returned as to see why the equality is not flipping from true to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can create a css with `.active` appended `.accordion-tab`, for instance `accordion-tab.active` then add background-ground `/wp-content/uploads/Nav-Arrow-up.png`

In your query try

```
$('.accordion-tab').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```